# Aplicación wpf no conecta con localdb error 50

Tags: sql-server, wpf

Buenas,

Esta es la primera aplicación que desarrollo con wpf y bbdd local, y ando un poco perdido.
La bbdd está realizada en SQL Server 2014, y la aplicación en VS 2015. A la hora de publicar, lo hago con ClickOnce, y en requisitos indico que se ha de instalar SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

Pues bien, en mi ordenador y en otros con VS2015 instalado la aplicación funciona perfectacmente, pero en los demás no se conecta a la bbdd, ni con el VS2103 instalado.

El error que me da es: SQL Network Interfaces, error 50 - Se produjo un error de Local Database Runtime. La instancia de LocalDB especificada no existe.

Alguna idea?

Comment: como defines el conection string ? imagino defines el .mdf para un attach dinamico. Instalas el Sql Server Express en las pc de los usuarios donde ejecutas la aplicacion?

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MC20.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30".  En los pc de los usuarios he probado instalando tanto el Sql Server 2012 Express como el Sql Server 2012 Express LocalDB

Comment: el .mdf lo hago asi http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/919746/how-to-export-sql-server-database-as-an-mdf-file/ , y luego en VS lo añado al proyecto mediante "Agregar nuevo origen de datos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, pues después de mucho buscar, al final era un problema de versiones de la BBDD. Refinando más la búsqueda del error he llegado a:

> "The database...cannot be opened because it is version 782. This
>   server supports version 706 and earlier."

Para solucionarlo seguí la solución propuesta por [user3390927](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346647/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-782-this-server-supports-ve) :

```
ALTER DATABASE VJ_DATABASE
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;   
GO

100 = Sql Server 2008
110 = Sql Server 2012
120 = Sql Server 2014
```

A mi no me dejaba cambiar a la versión 110, pero a la 100 si. 
Y ahora ya funciona la aplicación en otros pcs.

Answer (score 0):

Si sigues los pasos del articulo que mencionas

[How To Export SQL Server Database As .MDF File](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/919746/how-to-export-sql-server-database-as-an-mdf-file/)

alli se esta adjuntando la db al servicio de Sql Server, en ese caso el connection string no deberia usar `AttachDbFilename`

Si usas el `Sql Server Management Studio` deberias poder ver la db listada dentro del servicio de Sql Server, si es asi entonces el connection string deberia ser

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=MC20;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

---

Si usas el connection string como

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MC20.mdf;Integrat‌​ed Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

quiere decir que el .mdf deberias poder visualizarlo en el `Solution Explorer` del proyecto que estas desarrollando, es mas al compilar este deberia copiarse al `\bin\Debug`

La db la agregas usando la opcion del VS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma tendras la db en el proyecto y si aplicara un attach dinamico

Comment: El articulo ese solo lo sigo para tener los archivos .mdf y .ldf, luego no lo adjunto al sql server. Lo que hago después es adjuntarlo al proyecto, he probado de 2 formas: creando una carpeta data -> Añadir elemento existente, o bien Agregar nuevo origen de datos. En ambos casos la bbdd es visible en el explorador de soluciones, y al compilar se copia en \bin\debug. Creo el instalador (ClickOnce), y en mi pc funciona, pero en la mayoría no.

Comment: Solo funciona en los pc con VS2015 instalado.

Comment: @Palmer en la pc del usuario instalas al menos el Sql Server Express ? porque requiere del servicio de sql server para poder realizar el attach dinamico del .mdf que estaria junto al .exe

Comment: He probado instalando tanto el SQL Server 2012 Express como el SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB

Comment: ok pero el servicio de sql express esta iniciado? puedes usar el Sql Server Configuration Manager para validarlo. Lo que no se es que se trata el esa version de LocalDB que mencionas,pero la version express por defecto se instala en la instancia .\SQLExpress o en .\v11 usa el Management Studio para validar el nombre correcto de la instancia donde se instala

Comment: Sí esta iniciado. De hecho me he dado cuenta de que solo está iniciado el SQLExpress, y en mi ordenador se inician SQLExpress y MSSQLServer, y en el VS la instancia por defecto es (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es el prerrequisito de localDB, debes incluirlo como un paquete previo de ClickOnce.

Debes crear un prerrequisito para ClickOnce. Estos serían los pasos:
1. Crear una carpeta, por ejemplo **SqlLocalDB2014**.
2. Dentro de la carpeta creada, crear un archivo XML llamado **product.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlLocalDB.12.0">
  <InstallChecks>
    <FileCheck
      Property="sqllocaldbVersion"
      FileName="sqlservr.exe"
      SearchPath="Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn"
      SpecialFolder="ProgramFilesFolder"
    />
  </InstallChecks>

  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile
      Name="x86\sqllocaldb.msi"
      HomeSite="sqllocaldb_32"
      PublicKey="3082010A0282010100E57C2F2D0CA9EC7AA834E04C3F7F490E0DB615AD1913DE528A26991571A962270737A5833082626C0BA3FD060D171406E6E0ADCC95960A205AA296E1E057303C5D629BC55D890CD034DFD9D8FA35EF11238BC0F9EB4AF439DA2F7110EB11B32C37A370E886173EEF2A46D08EC7B94800A137F1C7C8E7D21E6B4A2AF2C64C1D709F7CC368428E3CED811A52E33E32943D7E18F19BE44B5C11E4D6C3851E6C033073BCC9A8017D9DADD1F573F05B1A7B2F1F8B32BEB38EB53BD9F7FFF35FB3137C139357B8A05E359883A13434F2C5049FB9FE46170C91DFEF0F55F6ECCC39C96165A129EEBE11371BB76E4255C9CC35D152B303709C98349E2936A917195F0BBF0203010001"
    />
    <PackageFile
      Name="x64\sqllocaldb.msi"
      HomeSite="sqllocaldb_64"
      PublicKey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
    />
  </PackageFiles>

  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="x86\sqllocaldb.msi" Arguments="IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES" EstimatedInstallSeconds="90">
      <InstallConditions>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="ValueNotExists" String="InvalidPlatformOS" />
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0.1" String="InvalidPlatformOS" />
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="sqllocaldbVersion" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="2014.120.2000.8" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot" />
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="GeneralFailure" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
    <Command PackageFile="x64\sqllocaldb.msi" Arguments="IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES" EstimatedInstallSeconds="90">
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
        <BypassIf Property="sqllocaldbVersion" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="2014.120.2000.8" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot" />
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="GeneralFailure" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

3. En la carpeta raíz, crear otra carpeta llamada *en (aquí va la cultura del idioma deseado, en tu caso calculo será **es**)* y crear otro archivo XML llamado package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Package Name="DisplayName" LicenseAgreement="Eula.txt" Culture="Culture" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
   <PackageFiles>
     <PackageFile Name="Eula.txt" />
   </PackageFiles>
   <Strings>
     <String Name="Culture">en</String>
     <String Name="DisplayName">SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB</String>
     <String Name="sqllocaldb_32">http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/LocalDB%2032BIT/SqlLocalDB.msi</String>
     <String Name="sqllocaldb_64">http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/LocalDB%2064BIT/SqlLocalDB.msi</String>
     <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB. Please contact your administrator.</String>
     <String Name="GeneralFailure">An error occurred attempting to install SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB.</String>
     <String Name="InvalidPlatformOS">The current operating system version does not support SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB.</String>
     <String Name="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack">The current operating system does not meet Service Pack level requirements for SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB. Install the most recent Service Pack from the Microsoft download center at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads before continuing setup.</String>
   </Strings>
 </Package>
```

4. Copiar el archivo **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\License Terms\License_SqlLocalDB_1033.txt** dentro de la carpeta **en** y renómbralo como **eula.txt**.
5. Para instalar el paquete copiar la carpeta **SqlLocalDB2014** donde están ubicados los otros paquetes bootstrapper. Por ejemplo, **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages**.
6. Ahora se puede utilizar el paquete desde Visual Studio, sin embargo, se debería tener el componente instalado en la misma ubicación que la aplicación. Se necesitan descargar los dos archivos especificados en el archivo **package.xml** y colocarlos en la carpeta **x86** o **x64** dentro de la carpeta **SqlLocalDb2014**.
7. Finalmente, este paquete es sólo para ingles pero soporta múltiples idiomas aplicándolo en la carpeta para cada cultura con sus archivos **package.xml** y **eula.txt**.

La respuesta original se encuentra [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832375/clickonce-prerequisites-where-is-sql-server-express-2014-localdb) (respuesta de [kjbartel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730559/kjbartel)).